# Flask-Restful Before request call

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I want to create an API using [Flask-RESTFUL](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/) and there is some stuff that I'm not able to find. I don't want to repeat myself every request, so I thought about using the before_request() and the tear_down() method.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Just use the normal `flask.before_request()`; nothing Flask-RESTful has to do here.

Comment: Hi, The problem is that I already try to use @before_request but looks like after doing that the args dictionary is empty, so I'm not sure if I am missing something there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `method_decorators` for a flask-restful `Resource` object.

```
class Resource(MethodView):
    """
    Represents an abstract RESTful resource. Concrete resources should
    extend from this class and expose methods for each supported HTTP
    method. If a resource is invoked with an unsupported HTTP method,
    the API will return a response with status 405 Method Not Allowed.
    Otherwise the appropriate method is called and passed all arguments
    from the url rule used when adding the resource to an Api instance. See
    :meth:`~flask_restful.Api.add_resource` for details.
    """
    representations = None
    method_decorators = []
```

If you take a look at the source code, it will apply the decorators in order:

```
for decorator in self.method_decorators:
    meth = decorator(meth)

resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)

if isinstance(resp, ResponseBase):  # There may be a better way to test
    return resp

representations = self.representations or OrderedDict()
```